# Complement of $a^n b^n c^n$

Tags: formal-languages

I am trying to find the complement of the language $L = \{ a^n b^n c^n \mid n \ge 0\}$.

I know that one of the things I gotta do is take out $n \ge 0$ so $\{a^n b^n c^n \mid n > 0\}$ but I feel there is not enough.Is making it so $a^i b^j c^k$ so that $i \neq j \neq k$ enough and make it so that $i,j,k > 0$?

Or am I completely off track?

Comment: 1) What about $bca$? 2) If you write "$i \neq j \neq k$", do you mean that also $i \neq k$? (Chains of $\neq$'s don't make sense, it's not a transitive relation!) 3) What does it mean to "find" $\overline{L}$"? A description in which form? Mathematically, $\overline{L} = \{ w \in \{a,b,c\}^* \mid w \not\in L \}$ is a perfectly correct description. (Note that you have to fix the alphabet in for the complement operator to make sense!)

Answer (score 2):

The complement is the set of all strings over alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ that are not of the form $a^i b^i c^i$ for some $i\geq 0$.  That includes all strings $a^ib^jc^k$ where $i\neq j$, $i\neq k$ and/or $j\neq k$, as you say, but also some other strings.  Mouse-over the box below for a hint.

> For example, $bacbabc$ is in the complement.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was thinking about that, then I would have to union { a c b} U { b c a} U {c a b } U { b a c}  U { a c b }

Answer (score 1):

First note that strings in $L= \{a^ib^jc^k: i=j=k\ge 0\}$ have a specific order and specific count of the symbols. The complement of $L$ (denoted as $L'$) then includes every string over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ that does not satisfy the order and/or the count constraints. This implies that $L'$ consists of the following languages over the alphabet $A=\{a,b,c\}$:

1. To relax the order constraint: a string in $L'$ could have either $ba, ca$,    and/or $bc$ as a substring. This can be represented as the regular expression: 
   $(a+b+c)^*(ba+cb+ca)(a+b+c)^*$.
2. To relax the count constraint: a string $w$ in $L'$ could have either $i\ne j$, $i\ne k$, or $j\ne k$. 
   Clearly, part 1 is a regular language and part 2 is CF, and hence their union $L'$ is CF.

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. There's a typo in `and/or bc as a`. I didn't recognise `^` as part of a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Note that every string in $\{a,b,c\}^*$ starts with a string from $L$ (even if in some cases that string is the empty string, with $n$=0).

If a string is not in $L$ then the prefix $a^nb^nc^n$ (for largest possible $n$) is  followed by a *non-empty* suffix.